# How to access local directory files using WAMP server?

Tags: html, video, wamp, block

I am new in html programing and actually I am self-taught. 
Recently I found a piece of software that let me pre-render videos to 60 fps.

I thought why not share the results with the world. So i read about how to code in html5. So I created a very simple looking site and everything worked perfectly when I start the html5 file (Videos are playing). So I read that  Wamp Server will give me opportunity to share this with the rest of the World.

But everytime I start Wamp and try to view the page neither the videos  or tumbnails of the videos load. Everything else like margins placement of the players text works but Wamp somehow blocks every content which is loaded in the html5 file like this:

`"D:/Downloads/Pixar Short Film Collection........ "`.

I repeat html5 works perfect if I start the index file from any browser but loaded through Wamp it can't load anything.

In IE10 under the videos is showing that is being blocked but in Chrome just blank.

It works when I make the html5 file to load the video from the directory "www", but this is a problem for me because it is going to be a video library site. My "C:" drive will be filled so if someone knows how to fix that it will be awesome.
PS(One week ago I had no such problem but it suddenly appeared. Since then I've been installing and uninstalling Wamp, but no luck)

And another thing, no matter what I did, following every tutorial for installing Wamp configuring my router/modem for 80 port and IP forwarding nothing seems to work even in my local network (typed IP in Chrome) I can't open the web page. Yet everything works, Wamp is green, and from the PC where Wamp is installed I can open the page, but in no other PC.

(I have prefect connection between the two PC's because from the one I can play games on the other without noticeable lag, but Wamp server is like a WALL)

PS 
If you are going to instruct me to unblock port 80 in my FireWall I have already done this on both PC's I am running Win8 in both machines!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with `HTML5` it is an `Apache` configuration issue.

From what you say I assume you have been double clicking on the index file from explorer (filemanager) while you develop and test your site. `BAD IDEA`.

Now you are using the browser to server the file via Apache ( it does not do this when you doubleclick on filenames in explorer ) you need to tell `Apache` that it has access to your video library which you placed on the D:\ drive.

To do this you need to configure `Apache` ( https.conf ) to know about your video library and be allowed to access it. To do this you need an `Alias`.

Now I have no idea what your setup is but lets assume you have created your site in the wamp folder structure `C:\wamp\www\` or `C:\wamp\www\sitename`

You will need to amend your `https.conf` file adding something like this to identify the video library and assign access privilages to it.

This can go at the bottom of the `httpd.conf` file after the `Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"` line

```
Alias /videolibrary "D:/Downloads/Pixar Short Film Collection........ "
<Directory "D:/Downloads/Pixar Short Film Collection........ ">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You can then address the individual videos in the library from your html as

```
/videolibrary/video1.xxx
```

using the alias `videolibrary` setup above and not

```
"D:/Downloads/Pixar Short Film Collection........ ".
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, this way it works perfectly. Only to add that before the alias in the html file you must add "/".
Now if someone can explain how to broatcast in the world wide web it will be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you can access localhost files using wamp via `C:/wamp/www/webitefolder/`